# Python: add a newline to a variable

Tags: python

I was working on some exercises for school and I can't get over this problem. Is there any way to add a newline to a variable? I tried just concatenating `\n` but it doesn't work. I want it to be able to return `allPrimes` with every number on a separate line.

```
def all_primes_upto(x):
    allPrimes = ''
    for i in range(x):
        if is_prime(i):
            allPrimes += i + '\n'
    return allPrimes
```

Comment: It would be useful to include the result you are getting as I suspect you are receiving an exception.

Comment: Standard variable naming for python is not `camelCasing`. Naming variable `all_prime` is a lot better than `allPrime`.

Comment: Also, when asking Python questions it is always a good idea to specify which version you are using as 2 and 3 have different behaviours that may lead to different answers.

Comment: okay, I will do that next time thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instead stored the values in a list, you could then print each item out one by one on individual lines

```
def all_primes_upto(x):
    allPrimes = []
    for i in range(x):
        if is_prime(i):
            allPrimes.append(i)
    return allPrimes

l = all_primes_upto(10)

for i in l:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't; your function should return a *list* of primes; the caller can join them into a single string if they want.

```
 def all_primes_upto(x):
     return [i for i in range(x) if is_prime(i)]

 prime_str = '\n'.join(str(x) for x in all_primes_upto(700))
```

Comment: This is a bit to complex for me but I have found the answer! Thanks

Comment: This is an example of a list comprehension, which is a single expression that defines lists that can otherwise be defined using the loop/conditional/append scheme shown in the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use the `+` operator on variables of different types: `i` is an `int`; `'\n'` is a `str`. To make the `+` work as a string concatenation you need both variables to be of type `str`. You can do that with the `str` function:

```
allPrimes += str(i) + '\n'
```

Note, however, that the other answers suggesting that your `all_primes_upto` function could return a list that the caller can join and print are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Right usage:

```
def all_primes_upto(x):
    allPrimes = ''
    for i in range(x):
        if is_prime(i):
            allPrimes += i + '\n'
            print(allPrimes)
```

use **print** instead of **return**